# How to deny ASP.NET Core Identity social registration by claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm using an OAuth social login with ASP.NET Core Identity and want to only accept new registrations for users with a specific claim, but cannot find a way to do this.

I realise I can use [Claims-Based Authorisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but this is after authentication and once the account has been created. I would like to let a user attempt to social sign-in, then at the point of receiving the IDPs token, inspect their claims and fail the login if I don't like a claim.

I've tried using the `options.Events.OnTicketReceived` and `options.Events.OnCreatingTicket` events in Startup.cs with the `Fail()` method, but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas?

A work-around might be to use Claims-Based Auth and then try and add in a handler that deleted the account, but this is inelegant.

Comment: What does your code for processing the external login and registration look like? e.g. Is it the Default UI?

Comment: Yes, default UI... services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

Comment: You might need to scaffold the external login page and customise the account creation process.

Comment: Hrm, was hoping to use the default UI to keep things simple, but yes, that's a good suggestion, thanks.